# How does the string that windows passes into command line argument when I choose to open a file with my application look?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm building some kind of a music player and I have a problem with a filename that is being passed into command line argument when I doubleclick it.

The player has a QLabel that shows the name of the song that is playing at the moment, which I get by parsing a filepath to the song that is stored in a QStringList. So when I open files from inside the application via QFileDialog command everything is working fine and I get a correct name, however when I try to open a file  via my application from outside of it (e.g. by doubleclicking an mp3 file) 
the string I get looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnB5V.png) (my system language is not chinese), it's different every time as well.

I'm passing the command line argument into my mainWindow class like this:

```
    QString arg;

    arg = argv[1];

    SoSoMain w(arg); //explicit SoSoMain(QString arg, QWidget *parent = 0);
```

Then it is added to a QStringList and from there it is accessed by a QLabel through another function that just cuts off everything before the slash and the extension, so I don't see how my code could cause that.

I'd be very grateful if someone could explain me why this happens and how to fix it. Thanks in Avance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `main` first you should do is create instance of `QApplication` class. You can do this like:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

Then you can get the list of arguments with

```
app.arguments();
```

which returns the `QStringList` with all commandline arguments.

> Usually arguments().at(0) is the program name, arguments().at(1) is
>   the first argument, and arguments().last() is the last argument.
>
> On Windows, the list is built from the argc and argv parameters only
>   if modified argv/argc parameters are passed to the constructor. In
>   that case, encoding problems might occur.
>
> Otherwise, the arguments() are constructed from the return value of
>   GetCommandLine(). As a result of this, the string given by
>   arguments().at(0) might not be the program name on Windows, depending
>   on how the application was started.

Comment: Thanks, I've done it, however it's still the same, nothing has changed.

Comment: I haven't see any your code so I cannot help. You can try print with `qDebug ()` the output of `arguments` method and watch where the song name is.

Comment: I think I actually got it - windows returns a string that uses backslashes as separators, and c++ confuses them with escape sequences, any idea how I could fix it?

Comment: If my answer helps you then mark it as valid please.